# How to set up Visual Studio 2013 similar to Dreamweaver

Tags: asp.net, web, visual-studio-2013, dreamweaver, publish

The company I work for has used Dreamweaver CS4 in the past, but we are transitioning to Visual Studio 2013.  This is new to me.

In Dreamweaver we would work locally and do edits then when everything was functioning correctly we would manually push an upload arrow to put it on the live site.

In Visual Studio 2013 I notice when we save our edits it automatically saves it directly to the live site.

How can I configure Visual Studio 2013 so that when I work on our clients websites I can first do it locally to be sure everything works fine.  Then when everything is functioning I could manually upload to the live site like we did in Dreamweaver.

Thanks for any help.  A walkthrough would be best since we don't know Visual Studio very well.

Thank you.

Comment: This is a *huge*, open-ended question. You should be running your application locally and then building and publishing releases to a live server (or some other intermediate environment); usually through some automated deployment system that interfaces with your version control system. There are literally unlimited ways of managing this. You need to start by getting some books or other resources on Visual Studio and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the live editing with VS2013. If you using VS2013 just as an HTML editor then its an overkill. VS2013 comes with a publishing wizard where you can setup the publish settings and publish your changes to the remote server.

In most cases remote editing is not good, but for minor cosmetic changes you can use live edit.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)